# Separar 6 imagens em 3 div, formando um slider com bxslider

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

Eu estou usando o plugin `bxslider`. Cada slider contém 6 imagens que são divididas em 3 `div`, cuja classes são `item_top` e `item_bottom`, para três imagens de cima e de baixo, respectivamente. Quando eu primeiramente peguei o código estático, estava assim:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="item_top">
            <img src="image_1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item_bottom">
            <img src="image_2.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

A cada 3 `li` forma um slide. O problema é que eu agora trago essas imagens do banco de dados, então não posso simplesmente adicionar duas `div` em cada `li` pois se não as imagens virão duplicadas. Assim, o código está assim agora:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="">
            <img src="<?php echo $x['imagem']; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

Procurei por soluções, e a melhor que eu achei foi remover do HTML as `li`, envolver com JavaScript contando cada 2 `div`, e então adicionar as classes para cada div `odd` e `even`. Desta maneira não funcionou como desejava, pois o plugin configurou as regras para as `div` ao invés das `li`, e mesmo adicioniando via JS, houve problemas.

Preciso de ajuda. Se desejaram, há um exemplo do HTML estático neste [site aqui](http://neoexordium.com/encontraauto/), na área "Concessionárias e Revendas", para verem como que preciso que esteja visualmente, vindo imagens do banco de dados.

Comment: Deixa eu entender direito, o problema é que pela base de dados você nao consegue controlar se vai vir 3 certinho ou de 2 em 2?

Comment: @RBoschini Isto. Da forma como está no meu código, que é o segundo bloco mostrado, ele apenas exibe três imagens em um slide, e mais três no próximo. Eu preciso que esse segundo trio de imagens fique abaixo do primeiro. Atualmente cada slide deveria conter 3 `li`, e dentro de cada uma, dois `div` com as classes citadas, porém se for necessário modificar a estrutura, e colocar três imagens por `div`, eu acredito que não haverá problemas, eu apenas preciso que fique da forma como está no link que passei. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo link que você passou de exemplo, eu sugiro que você crie um campo em sua tabela para identifique se a imagem é topo ou bottom e o retorno da consulta ficaria:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($imagem as $x){ ?>
    <li>
      <?php if ($x['nome-do-campo'] == 'top'){ ?>
        <div class="item_top">
            <img src="<?php echo $x['imagem']; ?>"/>
        </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="item_bottom">
            <img src="<?php echo $x['imagem']; ?>"/>
        </div>
      <?php }?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu muito certo porque a condição ainda vai exibir apenas uma imagem em cada div.